# How to enhance purity of function if we are using closures

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, closures

I have a pseudo-function as below

```js
let counter = 0;

function createNewFile() {
  const fileName = `book_${counter++}`;

  //...write file or whatever
};
```

The above function `createNewFile` definitely not ideal as it relies on external variable `counter` which may be changed unexpectedly. I'm thinking to reduce the chances of that happening, by closures and IIFE as below

```js
const counter = (() => {
  let counter = 0;
  return () => counter++;
})();

console.log(counter())
console.log(counter())

/*
function createNewFile() {
  const fileName = `book_${counter()}`;

  //...write file or whatever
};
*/
```

The code above served the purpose which now the `counter` is arguably "harder" to be changed "accidentally".

However, I'm wondering from functional programming perspective, how can we improve both the function `counter` and `createNewFile`? Because clearly both violated `pure function` rules, where both function are not giving same output on every single execution, I'm curious how to enhance the code given the use case?

Comment: The question doesn't make sense for me. You want to avoid the global variable by using a function state and you want a pure function that has a state through a closure. What does this even mean? A pure function doesn't have a state.

Comment: For a function like yours, which is basically a generator, "purity" is not really a relevant concept.

Comment: As long as the action is going to be writing to the file system, it'll be impure anyway, because of the side effect... Isn't it, then, irrelevant whether or not it relies on mutable state?

Comment: Potential duplicate? [Implement a Bi-Directional Counter in Functional Programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32235143)

Comment: The *purest*, but anyhow most intuitive, approach was to pass the counter as argument to ... `function createNewFile(counterValue) { /* ... */ }` ... like ... `createNewFile(counter);` ... thus another part of the program is responsible for the management of `counter` and how to utilize it with `createNewFile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is concerned with two effects:

- mutation by relying on a local variable
- I/O by writing to the file system

You can simply avoid local variables by passing them as arguments. The state is moved to the call stack. You cannot avoid all mutations using this techniques, though. For this reason functional programming often supplies persistent data structures, a clever form of immutability.

The I/O effect is harder to deal with. In Javascript I/O is often async hence promises are used to encode such computations. Unfortunately promises have a rather unprincipled semantics from a functional angle, so I am going to use a raw continuation type to show how to defer I/O effects under the hood:

```
function createNewFile(counter, data) {
  const fileName = `book_${counter}`;
  return k => {run: k(writeFile(fileName, data))}
};

const description = createNewFile(1, someData);

description.run(checkSuccess);
```

Instead of performing the effect we merely get back a description of this very action. The function is not particularly useful on its own. We need means to apply its result to other pure functions or to combine it with other descriptions without actually performing the effect, but this would go beyond the scope of this answer.